# Special characters show up as Ã¦ Ã¸, Ã¥

Tags: javascript, c#, character-encoding

I have a variable in C# with the special characters including æ ø å.

In C#, i encode it using `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`. I then use JavaScript to display the variable on my website. Every special character (quotation marks etc) except æøå works.

In the source code of the website, the æ ø å characters look like this:

```
&#195;&#166; &#195;&#184; &#195;&#165;
```

However, in the browser they look like this:

```
Ã¦ Ã¸ Ã¥
```

How can I display æ ø å correctly?

Comment: You are seeing them as UTF8. There must be some encoding problem.

Comment: Xanatos is right. The encoding is incorrect. Try changing the encoding format...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use HTML codes to get same characters:
æ : `&aelig;`
ø : `&oslash;`
å : `&aring;`

[Helpful Link](http://www.starr.net/is/type/htmlcodes.html)